# Arrow button with smooth rounded corners

Tags: css

I want to create a 'next button' where the right corner is an arrow and the corners are rounded smoothly.

How can I create an arrow button with smooth rounded corners like in this picture (and make all these effects)?

[image]

Here is my attempt ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d4vm5/242/)):

```
.arrow_btn {
    position: relative;
    background: #fa963e;
    border: 3px solid #f5a742;
    border-radius: 5px; 
}
.arrow_btn:after{
    left: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 5px;    
}
.arrow_btn:after {
    border-color: rgba(250, 150, 62, 0);
    border-left-color: #fa963e;
    border-width: 14px;
    margin-top: -14px;
    border-radius: 5px;    
}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: You should specify some attempt from that jsfiddle in the question.

Comment: I think you can't do the 'active' status with css, because you use border in .arrow_btn:after.  Try to cut it as img.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of thing really ought to be done with SVG, not CSS.

CSS is great at what it's designed for -- page layout. It sucks when you start trying to use it to draw graphics. It can do basic stuff fairly easily and that makes people think it can do anything... well, yes, it can, but it gets ugly pretty quickly.

SVG is explicitly designed for drawing graphics, and is very good at it. It can be embedded directly into your page or as a separate file like any other image. It's scalable and can be manipulated and animated via javascript... and it's dead easy to use.